# C# Parallel.Foreach with XML

Tags: c#, xml, parallel.foreach

I'm brand new to C# though have some minor experience with other languages and have hit a brick wall.

The code below works exactly as expected:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("config.xml");
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
   string name = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
   string ips = node.Attributes["ip"].Value;
   string port = node.Attributes["port"].Value;
   Console.WriteLine(name + " | " + ips + ":" + port);
}
```

I get out exactly what I am expecting with zero errors, however the following code has got me stumped. I am hoping someone can explain what I am doing wrong as I feel like I am perhaps missing something fundamental.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("config.xml");
node = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
Parallel.ForEach(node,
      (item) => {
      string name = item.Attributes["name"].Value;
      string ips = item.Attributes["ip"].Value;
      string port = item.Attributes["port"].Value;
      Console.WriteLine(name + " | " + ips + ":" + port);
      });
```

I am simply trying to run each iteration of the loop in parallel. When I try compile I get the following error:

**CS0411    The type arguments for method 'Parallel.ForEach
(IEnumerable, Action)' cannot be inferred from the usage. 
Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.**

Example XML below:

```
<item name="pc01" ip="192.168.0.10" port="80"><!--PC01--></item>
<item name="pc02" ip="192.168.0.11" port="80"><!--PC02--></item>
<item name="pc03" ip="192.168.0.12" port="80"><!--PC03--></item>
<item name="pc04" ip="192.168.0.13" port="80"><!--PC04--></item>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: As an aside, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) states that `XmlDocument` is not guaranteed thread safe.  Though it's not too likely queries will cause an issue, this is potentially risky.  Do you really have a performance problem in the single-threaded case?

Comment: @Charles Mager, I believe XmlDocument should fine across threads if you are only reading.

Comment: @SLaks, I have a time sensitive application where if one iteration in a  foreach loop is delayed due to execution time, it will cause issues for all subsequent iterations due to compounding execution time delays. Running these in parallel should avoid that issue.

Comment: Curious as to why I have down votes for asking this question? I searched the net for answers, no luck, searched this site for answers, no luck, asked a question to understand where I am going wrong and get down voted, can the down voters please explain their rational for this and also explain why they would not leave a reason for the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Cast` non generic types. Full solution below.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml="<root><item name='pc01' ip='192.168.0.10' port='80'><!--PC01--></item><item name='pc02' ip='192.168.0.11' port='80'><!--PC02--></item><item name='pc03' ip='192.168.0.12' port='80'><!--PC03--></item><item name='pc04' ip='192.168.0.13' port='80'><!--PC04--></item></root>";
        XmlDocument doc=new XmlDocument();
        // doc.Load("config.xml");
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        var nodeList=doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
        Parallel.ForEach(nodeList.Cast<XmlNode>(),
              item => {
                  string name=item.Attributes["name"].Value;
                  string ips=item.Attributes["ip"].Value;
                  string port=item.Attributes["port"].Value;
                  Console.WriteLine(name + " | " + ips + ":" + port);
              });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: That was spot on in terms of a solution. I was also able to use the doc.load("config.xml") which is exactly what I was looking for. I'll need to read up on the detail on Casting non generic types as I really don't understand what that means atm, but now I have something to aim at. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are the items displaying in the console out of sequence?
You can safely call `Console.WriteLine` from multiple threads but I wouldn't count on the items actually getting written to the console in the expected sequence. I'd expect them to *usually* get written in the expected sequence and then sometimes not.   That's the behavior of multithreaded execution. It will do what you expect it to do, but *never* count on it happening in the expected sequence, even if you test over and over and over and it does happen in the expected sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Scott, I am after parallel execution specifically for speed of return and avoidance of execution queues as the application I am writing is relying on response times rather than response order.